# Good Sources for simple/gradual exposure to Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, design-principles

I would like to set myself a goal to introduce myself to a new design pattern every week. Because I work at an internship right now, its hard to get me to do this because I always feel guilty that I should be doing work stuff & not learning a pattern.

**Do you know of any good sources, preferably website tutorials/demonstations but also books, that cover both Design Patters & Application Architecture/Patterns. Do you know of any good sources that are not just blocks of text (which is not the best way I learn), I prefer to follow tutorials or see graphical demonstrations of the pattern?**

I have googled for good sources but they seem to either only cover some design patterns or are huge blocks of text to read.

Answer (score 1):

[Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126) is a great gentle introduction.

Answer (score 0):

The two I like and in the order I like

1. http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns
2. http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My choices are as follows:

1. [Vince Huton's DP](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/)
2. [Design PAtterns](http://www.oodesign.com/)
3. [JUnit Cook's Tour](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm)

[JUnit Cookbook](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm) provides brilliant example of quite a few patterns - really worth checking.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at clean coders videos - https://cleancoders.com/videos/clean-code/design-patterns